# Font doesn't change in math mode with mathasfont

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, math-fonts, mathastext

I'm trying to change math font to sans serif font (the same I use in the rest of the document) with mathastext package. Letters change but numbers doesn't do it and I don't know why. This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Margin

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,mathrsfs,subdepth}
% amsmath   align equations
% tikz      create graphic elements
% subdepth  equalise the height of sub­scripts in math mode
% mathrsfs  handwritting math font

\usepackage{color, fancyhdr, fontspec, ragged2e, subfiles, titlesec}
% Color     text and background color
% Fancyhdr  customize headers and footers
% Fontspec  change main font
% Ragged2e  align text
% Subfiles  han­dle multi-file projects
% Titlesec  titles style

% ---------- COLOR PACKAGE ----------
\definecolor{amarillo}{RGB}{255,227,54}
\definecolor{azul}{RGB}{0,11,63}
\definecolor{blanco}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{255,49,127}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{5,187,136}

% ---------- FANCYHDR PACKAGE ----------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0} % Deletes header line
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\colorbox{amarillo}{Página \thepage}} % Numbering pages

% ---------- FONTSPEC PACKAGE ----------
\setmainfont[
BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-RegularItalic.ttf,
]{Quicksand-Regular.ttf} % Main font, loaded

% ---------- MATHASTEXT PACKAGE ----------
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

% ---------- TITLESEC PACKAGE ----------
\titlespacing{\section}{0}{-1cm}{1cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{2cm}{0.75cm}{0.5cm}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0}{0}{0.1cm}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries\LARGE}{}{1cm}{\centering}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\bfseries\Large}{}{0}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\bfseries\large}{}{0}{}[]

% ---------- OTHERS ----------
\setlength{\parskip}{0} \setlength{\parindent}{0} % Paragraph formatting

\begin{document}

\subfile{sections/unidad4}

\end{document}
```

*I'd tried to translate (from spanish) the better I could, sorry for mistakes.*

Then, when I write in math mode:

```
\textbf{Math mode:} \\
\( 0123456789 \quad ABCDEFGHIJ\) \\
\\
\textbf{Text mode:} \\
0123456789 \quad ABCDEFGHIJ
```

[image: math mode vs text mode]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the `fontspec` package with the `no-math` option (see the manual for this package) your problem should be solved. Also, I suggest to write `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` instead of `\setlength{\parskip}{0}` (see the warnings in the log file after compilation).

## Output

*(The horizontal rule connects the top and bottom part of the page and represents the image break only.)*

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % Margin

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,mathrsfs,subdepth}
% amsmath   align equations
% tikz      create graphic elements
% subdepth  equalise the height of sub­scripts in math mode
% mathrsfs  handwritting math font

\usepackage{color,fancyhdr,ragged2e,subfiles,titlesec}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
% Color     text and background color
% Fancyhdr  customize headers and footers
% Fontspec  change main font
% Ragged2e  align text
% Subfiles  han­dle multi-file projects
% Titlesec  titles style

% ---------- COLOR PACKAGE ----------
\definecolor{amarillo}{RGB}{255,227,54}
\definecolor{azul}{RGB}{0,11,63}
\definecolor{blanco}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{255,49,127}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{5,187,136}

% ---------- FANCYHDR PACKAGE ----------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Deletes header line
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\colorbox{amarillo}{Página \thepage}} % Numbering pages

% ---------- FONTSPEC PACKAGE ----------
\setmainfont[
BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-RegularItalic.ttf,
]{Quicksand-Regular.ttf} % Main font, loaded

% ---------- MATHASTEXT PACKAGE ----------
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

% ---------- TITLESEC PACKAGE ----------
\titlespacing{\section}{0}{-1cm}{1cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{2cm}{0.75cm}{0.5cm}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0}{0}{0.1cm}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries\LARGE}{}{1cm}{\centering}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\bfseries\Large}{}{0}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]{\bfseries\large}{}{0}{}[]

% ---------- OTHERS ----------
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Paragraph formatting

\begin{document}

\textbf{Math mode:} \\
\( 0123456789 \quad ABCDEFGHIJ\) \\
\\
\textbf{Text mode:} \\
0123456789 \quad ABCDEFGHIJ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good. You have my appreciation. (+1).

Comment: I didn't know the **no-math** option for Fontspec. Now my LaTeX document looks as I want ♥  Thank you, thank you, thank you!